# How to find a specific number of digits in string

Tags: powershell

I don't understand the Regex :(
I want to find if a path contains only 7 digits
For an example:

```
C:\Users\3D Objects\1403036 --> the result should be 1403036

C:\Users\358712\1403036 --> the result should be 1403036
```

and so on

I have tried:

```
$FilesPath -match '([\d{1,7}]{7})')
```

and

```
$FilesPath -match '(\d{7})')
```

Currently I am working with that:

```
$FilesPath = Read-Host -Prompt
if ($Matches[1].Length -eq '7') {
        $FolderNumber = $Matches[1] 
    }
```

This is not right because there is no match if the path contains the number 3 in the path

If this is the case:

```
C:\Users\3D Objects\1403036854 --> More than 7 digits the result should be empty
```

or

```
C:\Users\3874113353D Objects\1403036 --> Should return result for 1403036
```

I don't have an array, just want to get if there is a number with exactly 7 digits and don't if contains less or more than 7 digits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
# as example the paths as aray to loop over
'C:\Users\3D Objects\1403036', 'C:\Users\358712\1403036', 
'C:\Users\somewhere\1234567', 'C:\Users\3D Objects\1403036854' | ForEach-Object {
    # return the number anchored at the end of the string with exactly 7 digits
    ([regex]'\D(\d{7})$').Match($_).Groups[1].Value
}
```

Output:

```
1403036
1403036
1234567
```

---

This:

```
$path = 'C:\Users\3D Objects\1403036'
$result = ([regex]'\D(\d{7})(?:\D|$)').Match($path).Groups[1].Value
```

directly assigns the match to variable `$result` and will be the matching numeric value if it matches or `$null`. Regex **method** `.Match()` does not populate the `$matches` array.

Using the regex **operator**, which does populate the `$matches` array, you can also do this:

```
if ($path -match '\D(\d{7})(?:\D|$)') {
    $result = $matches[1]
}
```

Regex details:

```
\D           # Match a single character that is NOT a “digit” (any decimal number in any Unicode script)
(            # Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   \d        # Match a single character that is a “digit” (any decimal number in any Unicode script)
      {7}    # Exactly 7 times
)
(?:          # Match the regular expression below
             # Match this alternative (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
      \D     # Match a single character that is NOT a “digit” (any decimal number in any Unicode script)
   |
             # Or match this alternative (the entire group fails if this one fails to match)
      $      # Assert position at the end of the string, or before the line break at the end of the string, if any (line feed)
)
```

Comment: Please look at the updated message

Comment: @Bandit The array was just to show as example (a demo if you like). Of course you can do string-by-string like `$result = ([regex]'\D(\d{7})$').Match('C:\Users\3D Objects\1403036').Groups[1].Value` and this will either return the number `1403036` or `$null` in case of `$result = ([regex]'\D(\d{7})$').Match('C:\Users\3D Objects\1403036854').Groups[1].Value` for instance

Comment: You mean like this?

if (([regex]'\D(\d{7})$').Match($FilesPath).Groups[1].Value) {

        $FolderNumber = $Matches[1] 
}

Comment: This is not working for 
C:\Temp\1403036_140303

Comment: @Bandit, NO, you are confusing the regex method `.Match()` with what you can do with the **operator** `-match`.. I'll update my answer shortly

Comment: Thank you
Why there is no result for C:\Temp\Folder1403036(140303) ?
There is a 7 digits...

Comment: Can you explain what does each letter?  '\D(\d{7})$'

In this case I expect to get result
C:\Users\ncarmona\3874747 Objects\140254

Comment: @Bandit `\D` means a non-digit character. `\d` means a digit. `{7}` looks for exactly 7 digits and `$` anchors to the end

Comment: The 7 digits can be in the middle also...not at the end

Comment: Maybe this '\D(\d{7})' ?

Comment: If the path has 7 digits anywhere I want results if have 9 I need to get null
C:\Users\38747488\Objects 1402547\  -> should get result
C:\Users\3874747 Objects\140254 --> should get results

Comment: I need to understand. I did some tests and it looks like '\D(\d{7})' is right but when I test it in the https://regex101.com/ its not.
Its really answer my question? ('\D(\d{7})') without the $ at the end
Can you explain please?

Comment: Why I don't get result for "\\XXXXXX.com\global\Patch Managment\1399771\" ?
Can you fix it please?
@Theo

Comment: @Bandit It is a pity your post only included examles where the 7-digit number is always at the end of each path.. Please see my final edit to also catch 7-digit groups anywhere within the path

Comment: Thank you Theo
I am guessing that if the name contain 2 groups the match will be for the first right?

Comment: @Bandit Yep, in that case you will receive the first (leftmost) match

Comment: There is an option to know if more then 1 group of 7 digits found?  (any command?)
Thanks again Theo

Comment: I want to know if this case is happening

Comment: Hi @Theo
In that case the count is not working because there is always 1 result... what can I do in order to know if there is more than 1 group in the name?